# GKE ingress pass cookie as header

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, proxy, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I would like to use some kubernetes ingress (doesn't matter the ingress type) on google cloud  GKE 1.19.7-gke.1302, and nginx ingress deployed by nginx-ingress-0.8.0 helm chart, and my need is to fetch a cookie and use it later to authenticate to our service. When I use nginx as deployment it works, but when I use nginx ingress it seems to ignore the annotation.

I tried using this configuration snippet for the nginx ingress, which works on the nginx deployment but not on the ingress:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  proxy_set_header "Authorization" "Basic $cookie_myToken";
```

And this is my entire ingress yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-nginx-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # enable backend redirections
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    # enable stickiness
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header "Authorization" "Basic $cookie_myToken";  
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: my-tls
    hosts: 
    - "test.com"
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: my-nodeport
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
    - host: "test.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-nodeport
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What GKE version are you using? How did you deploy `Nginx Ingress Controller`? What exactly is your error? Anything suspicious in logs?

Comment: GKE 1.19.7-gke.1302, and nginx ingress deployed by nginx-ingress-0.8.0 helm chart, nothing in the logs but the configuration snippet is just ignored.

Comment: Could you redeploy `Nginx Ingress` 0.44 using [this steps](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#using-helm) ?

Comment: Yes, reinstalling nginx ingress to the latest version with helm solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this answer to make it more visible as issue was identified and solved in `comment section`.

Root cause of this issue was `Nginx Ingress Controller` misconfiguration.

In the OP's setup `Nginx Ingress Controller`, `v.0.8.0` was used. After redeploying `Nginx Ingress` to latest version (v0.44.0) from [Nginx Ingress Documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#using-helm) it started working properly.

> Yes, reinstalling nginx ingress to the latest version with helm solved the problem.